# UWP App compiled with .NET native tool chain crashes on startup due to custom style

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have confirmed that the mere presence (even if it doesn't get used) of the following Style in a Xamarin Forms UWP project's App.xaml ResourceDictionary results in a crash on startup for the UWP app when compiled with .NET native tool chain enabled in release mode (x64, but don't think it matters in this case). Works 100% fine without .NET native tool chain enabled, but would really like to keep this custom style in AND reap the benefits of a faster app compiled natively. Does anybody know why it's crashing the app? I cannot even seem to figure out how to get a more detailed error message other than what I see in Windows event viewer, which just says Windows.UI.Xaml.dll is the faulting module name.

**UPDATE:** by turning "optimize code" off and enabling DEBUG in Release mode and running from VS, I was able to get the below.... which led me to an [great] animation library I was using called [Xamanimation](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/Xamanimation)... still not sure the link between the custom style in my UWP app.xaml and this problem, but fixing this real problem of course solved everything (i.e. the style was a red herring). Added an answer on this below.

> System.Private.Interop.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ThrowOnExternalCallFailed(int
>   hr, System.RuntimeTypeHandle typeHnd) Line 1189   at
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Interop\src\Shared\McgMarshal.cs(1189)
>
> System.ArgumentException   HResult=0x80070057   Message=Value does not
>   fall within the expected range.   Source=   StackTrace:       StackTrace  "   at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ThrowOnExternalCallFailed(Int32
>   hr, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHnd) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Interop\src\Shared\McgMarshal.cs:line
>   1189\r\n   at __Interop.ComCallHelpers.Call(__ComObject __this,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle __typeHnd, Int32 __targetIndex, Double arg0)\r\n
>   at __Interop.ForwardComStubs.Stub_22[TThis](__ComObject __this, Double
>   value, Int32 __targetIndex)\r\n   at
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.IUIElement__Impl.Stubs.put_Opacity(__ComObject __this,
>   Double value)\r\n   at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.put_Opacity(Double
>   value)\r\n   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementTracker`2.UpdateOpacity(VisualElement
>   view, FrameworkElement frameworkElement) in
>   D:\\a\\1\\s\\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP\\VisualElementTracker.cs:line
>   518\r\n   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementTracker`2.UpdateNativeControl()
>   in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP\VisualElementTracker.cs:line
>   236\r\n   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementTracker`2.OnRedrawNeeded(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\\a\\1\\s\\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP\\VisualElementTracker.cs:line
>   409\r\n   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs
>   e)\r\n   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.BatchCommit() in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:line 572\r\n   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.AnimationExtensions.HandleTweenerUpdated(Object o,
>   EventArgs args) in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\AnimationExtensions.cs:line 274\r\n
>   at System.EventHandler.InvokeOpenStaticThunk(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e)\r\n   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)\r\n
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Tweener.b__22_0(Int64 step) in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Tweener.cs:line 92\r\n   at
>   System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg)\r\n   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Ticker.SendSignals(Int64 step) in
>   D:\\a\\1\\s\\Xamarin.Forms.Core\\Internals\\Ticker.cs:line 136\r\n
>
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Ticker.SendSignals(Int32 timestep) in
>   D:\\a\\1\\s\\Xamarin.Forms.Core\\Internals\\Ticker.cs:line 125\r\n
>
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsTicker.RenderingFrameEventHandler(Object
>   sender, Object args) in
>   D:\\a\\1\\s\\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP\\WindowsTicker.cs:line 25\r\n 
>   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)\r\n   at
>   __Interop.Intrinsics.HasThisCall__51(Object __this, IntPtr pfn, Object arg0, Object arg1)\r\n   at __Interop.ReverseComStubs.Stub_41(Object
>   __this, Void* unsafe_sender, Void* unsafe_args, IntPtr __methodPtr)"  string

```
        <Style x:Key="FormTextBoxStyle" TargetType="uwp:FormsTextBox">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="ForegroundFocusBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackHighBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="PlaceholderForegroundBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="PlaceholderForegroundFocusBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextChromeBlackMediumLowBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundFocusBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="uwp:FormsTextBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>

                                <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Grid
                                                    x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                    Background="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                                    BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBorderThemeBrush}"
                                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                                    <TextBlock
                                                        x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                                        FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                                        FontSize="12"
                                                        FontStyle="Normal"
                                                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                        Text="&#xE10A;" />
                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                        To="0"
                                                                        Duration="0" />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>

                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border
                                x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.RowSpan="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            <Border
                                x:Name="BorderElement"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.RowSpan="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                                x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                FontWeight="Normal"
                                Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <ScrollViewer
                                x:Name="ContentElement"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding ForegroundFocusBrush}"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                            <ContentControl
                                x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderForegroundBrush}"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                IsTabStop="False" />

                            <Button
                                x:Name="DeleteButton"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                MinWidth="34"
                                Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding ForegroundFocusBrush}"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundHoverOpacity}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForegroundFocusBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding BackgroundFocusBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding ForegroundFocusBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                        <Storyboard>

                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: ,According to your description, I can not reproduce your issue, so can you provide one simple at github that can reproduce your issue, I will download your sample to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this little hack using the [Xamanimation](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/Xamanimation) library for adding an animation to some items on my ContentPage Appearing event does not work for the FadeToAnimation (although it works just fine for TranslateToAnimation):

```
    <xamanimation:StoryBoard x:Key="EntriesAnimation" Target="{x:Reference UserEntries}">
        <xamanimation:FadeToAnimation Opacity="0" Duration="0" />
        <xamanimation:FadeToAnimation Opacity="1" Duration="500" />
    </xamanimation:StoryBoard>
```

There were no issues with this in Debug mode, or in Release with .NET Native compilation disabled. But with it enabled, it was crashing the app.

The workaround was simple, I just set the Opacity property directly on the Target to 0 and got rid of the first line (`<xamanimation:FadeToAnimation Opacity="0" Duration="0" />`) and presto - everything was fine.